# Block web executable file types from running in specific directory?

Tags: php, apache

I have an uploading script that uploads all user submitted files to one directory and I want to make that directory show pictures/audio/video like normal but serve any "executable" file types (.php, .js, .cgi, .html, etc.) as either plain/text or application/octet-stream programmatically.

Currently, I have this in my .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
php_flag engine off
RemoveHandler .cgi .pl .py .php4 .pcgi4 .php .php3 .phtml .pcgi .php5 .pcgi5 .pyc .pyo .php2 .html .xhtml .htm
RemoveType .cgi .pl .py .php4 .pcgi4 .php .php3 .phtml .pcgi .php5 .pcgi5 .pyc .pyo .php2 .html .xhtml .htm
AddType text/plain cgi pl py php4 pcgi4 php php3 phtml pcgi php5 pcgi5 pyc pyo php2 html xhtml htm
```

As you can tell, it's quickly becoming hard to manage and that still leaves out any file types which I wouldn't know about to still execute.

Is it possible for Apache to do this or is it better off being handled by php instead?

I'm still relatively new to server configuration so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Might be better if you rely on PHP to set the headers. Set the executuables mime type to ```plain/text``` and the browser will parse it as text. There should be plenty of libraries that perform this action out there